# how to both reorder and substitute parts of a string in r?

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I am trying to translate some textual information into R scripts. For that I need to substitute and reorder parts of the strings.

```
example <- "varA is 1 and not varB is 1"
```

This is what I want as a result (a part of an R script):

```
exampleTrans <- "varA == 1 & varB != 1"
```

This is what I can do now:

```
exampleTrans <- gsub(" is "," == ", example)
exampleTrans <- gsub(" and ", " & ", exampleTrans)
print(exampleTrans)
[1] "varA == 1 & not varB == 1"
```

The first part of the string is exactly what I wanted, so now I only need to change somthing in the second part. "not varB == 1" needs to be changed into "varB != 1".

Does anyone have an idea about how to do that? Is it even possible? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my solution using `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(exampleTrans, "not (\\w+) =", "\\1 !")
[1] "varA == 1 & varB != 1"
```

Explanation: replace a pattern `not (word) =` with `(word) !`, where `word` is a variable name without spaces. Adjust it accordingly if you have specific variable names, containing e.g. digits or underscores.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is my solution :

- First you need to split the string in two parts using `str_split()`. This is useful to detect the part of the string where you have the `not`.
- then you substitute `is` with `==` when `not` isn't there and with `!=` when `not` is there.
- Then you can collapse the result with `&`.

Here is my code :

```
library("stringr")
example <- "varA is 1 and not varB is 1"
out  <- str_split(example, "and")[[1]] 
ifelse(grepl(pattern = "not", x = out), sub(pattern = "([[:alpha:]]+) is ([[:digit:]]+)", replacement = "\\1 != \\2", x = out), 
    sub(pattern = "([[:alpha:]]+) is ([[:digit:]]+)", replacement = "\\1 == \\2", x = out)
   )
paste(out, collapse = "&")
```

Hope it works !